# Listar String en un select PHP/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

> 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30

Almacenada en la BD en un solo campo `varchar 300`, 
¿Se puede desmenuzar esta cadena en variables separadas para alimentar un select si es posible en JavaScript o JQuery?

Ejemplo 30 campos en el select:

```html
<select id="numero_cono">
<option disabled="" selected="" value="VACIO">                                                 Seleccione                                                                                        </option>                                                                                       <option value="1">
  1                                                                                             </option>                                                                                   <option value="2">
 2                                                                                             </option>
<option value="3">
 3                                                                                       </option>
```

Uso este metodo ajax para mandar un valor a la base de datos y traer una respuesta en formato json , ¿De que forma puedo enviar el campo de "numero_cono" a un select de forma individual ?

```
   function NumeroConos(id_cono) {
      var ParamObjSend = {
        'id_cono' :id_cono,
      };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>AgregarOTController/NumeroConos",
    data: ParamObjSend,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(objView) {
      alert(var_dump(objView.NumeroConos.numero_cono));
      var items            = objView.NumeroConos.split(';');   
      alert(var_dump(items));
      $.each(items, function () {
        var option         = document.createElement('option');
        option.value       = $(this);
        option.textContent = $(this);
        $('#numero_conos').append(option);
      });   
    }
  });
}
```

Este es el metodo que trae los datos desde la bd y tranforma la respuesta a JSon

```
public function NumeroConos(){
 $Where['id_cono']       =$this->input->post('id_cono');
 $NumeroConos            =$this->MainModel->_sql('Conos',$Where,'');

 $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(
            json_encode(array(
                'success'=>true,
                'NumeroConos'=>$NumeroConos

            ))  
    );
  }
```

este es el json que mando de vuelta

> {"success":true,"NumeroConos":[{"id_cono":"1","descripcion_cono":"sdfasdf","color_cono":"Rojo","numero_conos":"1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50","token":"GcKegUhEh7kQAsf35fefkPmBMhwyKQvBFBcJ1W5z720xk9uegy","estado":"0"}]}

Este select manda el id al controlador mediante onchange

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">Color cono</span>
<label class="select">
<select id="id_conos" onchange="NumeroConos(this.value);">
<option disabled="" selected="" value="0">
Seleccione                                                                                    </option>
<?php foreach ($conos as $key =>$value) {?>
<option value="<?= $value->id_cono?>">
<?= $value->color_cono?>
</option>
<?php }?>
</select>
<i>
</i>
</label>
</div>
</section>
```

Este es el select que recibe los datos

```
<section class="col col-6">
<div class="input-group">                                                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Color cono</span>
<label class="select">
<select id="numero_conos">
</select>
<i>
</i>
</label>
</div>
</section>
```

al ejecutar obtengo el siguiente error de la consola

> Uncaught TypeError: objView.NumeroConos.split is not a function
>       at Object.success ((index):5701)
>       at l (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4)
>       at k (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6)

Retorna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La respuesta es `SI`. Muéstranos que has intentando, así podemos ver donde está el error. Tambien seria util saber cual es el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Estás usando AJAX?

Comment: si uso el metodo ajax de jquery

Comment: ¿El split te está devolviendo esos 30 objetos? WTF..

Comment: si devuelve los 50 solo que se saque captura a 30 , de que forma puedo acceder a los datos que están dentro ? gracias

Answer (score 2):

Basta con dividir el texto por medio del separador (`;`) para obtener un array con los elementos, iterarlos y agregarlos al select.

Lo que interesa es extraer `numero_conos` que está dentro del array `NumeroConos`.

```
function NumeroConos(id_cono) {
  var ParamObjSend = {
    'id_cono' :id_cono,
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>AgregarOTController/NumeroConos",
    data: ParamObjSend,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(objView) {
      var items = objView.NumeroConos[0].numero_conos.split(';');

      $.each(items, function () {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = $(this);
        option.textContent = $(this);
        $('#id_cant_combustible').append(option);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Primero accedemos a `NumeroConos`, luego al primer y único objeto (`[0]`) y finalmente a la propiedad `numero_conos`.

Comment: en que pate del metodo .done introduzco mi json ?

Comment: ¿Por qué has de introducirlo manualmente si dices que estás usando AJAX? Cuando haces una petición AJAX a PHP y responder con `echo`, esa será tu respuesta. En tu caso, responde con `echo $numeros;` donde `$numeros` es el texto de números separados por punto y coma.

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar respuesta actualizada.

Comment: gracias estimado , pero recibo un error , "Uncaught TypeError: objView.NumeroConos.split is not a function"

Comment: el error me lo da en la linea "var items = objView.NumeroConos.numero_conos.split(';');"

Comment: No es posible amigo mío por el simple hecho que envías: `'NumeroConos'=>$NumeroConos` lo que se traduce a `NumeroConos: '1;2;3;...'`. ¿Añadiste el `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: Fíjate en mi código, en la propiedad `dataType: 'json'`, es necesario para que la respuesta sea convertida a un objeto literal JavaScript.

Comment: sigue saliendo el mismo error , incluso agregando el dataType: 'json',

Comment: Imprime `objView` de una vez para saber qué demonios está trayendo si no es un JSON.

Comment: me retorna object 0 : [object Object] ;

Comment: Vale, está devolviendo un JSON con un array dentro. Entonces, reemplaza `objView.NumeroConos.split(';')` por `objView[0].NumeroConos.split(';')`.

Comment: aun así colocando lo que me dijiste no hay caso no funciona , de todas formas gracias por la ayuda estimado :)

Comment: Es muy difícil ayudarte si no das información precisa. Estoy adivinando cada vez que escribo. Ayúdanos a ayudarte y pon la mayor información relevante que puedas. Por ejemplo, actualiza tu pregunta y pon **la respuesta** que obtienes del servidor.

Comment: entiendo , obtengo este error desde la consola de google chrome Uncaught TypeError: objView.NumeroConos.split is not a function
    at Object.success ((index):5701)
    at l (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6)

Comment: El error ya está claro, lo que interesa saber **es la estructura de la respuesta** que obtienes desde el servidor. En pocas palabras, **quiero saber la estructura de** `objView` **para saber cómo está construido y poder saber de qué manera acceder a** `NumeroConos`. Actualiza tu respuesta y pega su contenido.

Comment: ahi sube el json en la pregunta gracias

Comment: Vaya, ¡era que lo hagas a la primera! Tenía una estructura totalmente diferente en mente. He actualizado mi respuesta, ahora sí debería funcionar.

Comment: gracias por toda la ayuda , funciona pero sucedió algo curioso , actualizare la pregunta , me retorna 30 Object, Object

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55919/discussion-between-javier-antonio-aguayo-aguilar-and-gustavo-garcia).

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la funcion explode en php que te devuelve un arreglo con los datos separados por tu delimitador

```
$array = explode(";", $cadena);
```

y despues llenar el select barriendo el array en un ciclo

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas utilizar el método [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
var resultado = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30";
var array = resultado.split(";");
```

Obtendrás un *array* de 30 elementos. Espero que te sirva para luego hacer la *SELECT* que necesitas.